# Check if random number exist in you list/array

Tags: java, android, arrays

In my java code, I randomly pick a number and fetch the value/string that the number is assigned to from my array. That works fine, but after it has been fetched I want to store the number in a list or array, then when the number is generated again I can check to see if that number exist in the array or list and if it does to pick another number, if it doesn't match display the value/string of that number from the array.xml. How can this be achieved? Is my code correct in achieving this?

array.xml

```
<array name="OneTimesTables">
    <item>1 x 1 = </item>
    <item>1 x 2 = </item>
    <item>1 x 3 = </item>
    <item>1 x 4 = </item>
    <item>1 x 5 = </item>
    <item>1 x 6 = </item>
    <item>1 x 7 = </item>
    <item>1 x 8 = </item>
    <item>1 x 9 = </item>
    <item>1 x 10 = </item>
    <item>1 x 11 = </item>
    <item>1 x 12 = </item>
</array>
```

My java code

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] MyArray;
TextView Questions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    final List<String> PastQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();

    MyArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.OneTimesTables);
    Questions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RandomTestActivity_textView);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RandomTestActivity_button);

    int count = (new Random()).nextInt(12);
    Questions.setText(MyArray[count]);
    PastQuestions.add(MyArray[count]);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count = (new Random()).nextInt(12);
            if (MyArray[count].equals(PastQuestions)) {
                int count2 = (new Random()).nextInt(12);
                Questions.setText(MyArray[count2]);
                PastQuestions.add(MyArray[count2]);
            } else {
                Questions.setText(MyArray[count]);
                PastQuestions.add(MyArray[count]);
            }
        }
    });
    RandomiseArray();
}

private void RandomiseArray() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String item: MyArray){
        list.add(item);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
}
}
```

Comment: Has the code correctly achieved this?

Comment: no it hasn't as it will print the same number over and over again!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), e.g. a [`HashSet<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). A set provides fast check to see if value already exists ([`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)).

**Example**

```
Random rnd = new Random();

// Generate 5 unique numbers 0-9
Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int number = rnd.nextInt(10);
    while (used.contains(number)) {
        System.out.println("Skipping duplicate: " + number);
        number = rnd.nextInt(10);
    }
    used.add(number);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

**Output**

```
0
2
7
6
Skipping duplicate: 2
4
```

---

Now, if you will be exhausting the list of available numbers, the retry `while` loop will begin to spin, randomly searching for an unused number.

If you know you'll be using all or most of the available numbers, it may be better to simply add all numbers to a list and shuffle it, then pull values from the list.

```
// Generate random list of 10 unique numbers 0-9
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    list.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output**

```
[6, 2, 3, 5, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occur here.

```
int count = (new Random()).nextInt(12);
if (MyArray[count].equals(PastQuestions)) {
    int count2 = (new Random()).nextInt(12);
    Questions.setText(MyArray[count2]);
    PastQuestions.add(MyArray[count2]);
} else {
    Questions.setText(MyArray[count]);
    PastQuestions.add(MyArray[count]);
}
```

if you want to make sure that the item is different with any item you have picked out in the PastQuestions, you need to compare `MyArray[count]` with every element in the `PastQuestions`. Meanwhile, you pick a number randomly if `MyArray[count].equals(PastQuestions)`, maybe it is likely to get past item again, so you need to redesign this part to think about this situation.

One solution maybe satisfy your requirement:

1. itemArray store all the items;
2. count store how many items you have picked; count = 0 initial
3. when click button, you random get a number: pick = (new Random()).nextInt(**12-count**);
4. add the item  itemArray[pick] to your PastQuestions.
5. remove this item from itemArray

So

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] MyArray;
TextView Questions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    final List<String> PastQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();

    MyArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.OneTimesTables);
    Questions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RandomTestActivity_textView);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RandomTestActivity_button);

    //The current length of PastQuestions
    int length = 0

    int count = (new Random()).nextInt(12);
    Questions.setText(MyArray[count]);
    PastQuestions.add(MyArray[count]);
    length++;
    MyArray.remove(count);

    //in order to access the length, you need a final variable
    final int[] lengthAccessInListenr = {length};

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count = (new Random()).nextInt(12-lengthAccessInListenr[0] );
            Questions.setText(MyArray[count]);
            PastQuestions.add(MyArray[count]);
            lengthAccessInListenr[0]++;
            MyArray.remove(count);
        }
    });
    RandomiseArray();
}

private void RandomiseArray() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String item: MyArray){
        list.add(item);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
}
}
```